# How would I add /api to these routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have bunch of routes that I can access through like localhost:3000/posts  localhost:3000/users

config/routes.rb looks like this

```
resources :posts do                                                                                                                                                                                             
    resources :comments, shallow: true do                                                                                                                                                                         
      delete :destroy_all, on: :collection                                                                                                                                                                        
    end                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    resources :images, shallow: true                                                                                                                                                                              
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                             

  resources :comments, only: [:new]                                                                                                                                                                               
  resources :users                                                                                                                                                                                                

  root 'welcome#index'
```

How can I modify it so I also have normal access and also API access to them such as
http://localhost:3000/api/posts
http://localhost:3000/api/users/new and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building an API, you should consider versioning, thus separating your JSON API from your HTML interface; this means pulling your JSON API out into separate controllers that exist in a versioned API namespace.

```
namespace :api do  
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :posts do
      resource :comments, shallow: true do
        delete :destroy_all, on: collection
      end
    end

    resources :comments
    resources :users
  end
end

resources :posts do
  resource :comments, shallow: true do
    delete :destroy_all, on: collection
  end
end

resources :comments
resources :users
```

These controllers would exist in `app/controllers/api/v1`.

Your route would now look like:

`/api/v1/posts`

Versioning your APIs is considered good practice because you want your API to remain consistent.

There's a great RailsCast on API versioning:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast